# change source to <audio> html5 element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I'm building a jquery/html5 audio player and I have some problems on changing the source to the audio tag. The method I've implemented works on all browsers except IE9.

Here is a sample of code:

```
audio = $("<audio>").attr("id", "audioElement")
                        .attr("preload", "auto")
                        .appendTo(player);

function addMp3Source(sourceUrl) {
    audio.empty();
    var newSrc = $("<source>").attr("src", config.tracksURL + sourceUrl).appendTo(audio);
}
```

On IE9, the source is changing, but when I'm playing the track, it's the old sound that plays. On other browsers works fine.

Any ideeas?

Comment: Maybe you need to remove the whole audio element and add a new one with the new source as a workaround.

Comment: All you doing in there is emptying the html/children of `<audio>` you should use `.remove()` and `$('<audio/>');` to create a new element audio, that way u loose trace of the old element, :)

Comment: so I can't change only the source? I already have some references to that audio tag, and if I remove the tag I lose the references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function addMp3Source(sourceUrl) {
    audio.empty();
    var newSrc = $("<source>").attr("src", config.tracksURL + sourceUrl).appendTo(audio);
    /****************/
    audio[0].pause();
    audio[0].load();//suspends and restores all audio element
    /****************/
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This approach worked for jQuery Mobile 1.0.1 in FF 10 and Chrome 16 on Mac OS X 10.7, while several other methods didn't.  However, I got the error `pause() is not a function`.  So, I removed   `audio[0].pause();` and now my revised audio sources play:-)